# Recursive multilevel taxonomy feeds Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds

I am currently using 2 feeds of [module Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to load a simple structure of nested taxonomies, with just 2 levels. I use two CSV files, one with the parent taxonomies, and the other with the children (see attached image to see the relationship through a PGUID, parent id).
But now the problem is that my client will want no 2 fixed levels, but 3, 4, or more, varying depending on demand. So I do not know how to optimize the load (it is running in a cron in Elyisia cron right now).
Must I create a new feed for each level? What happens if the levels differ from day to day? Is there any recursive solution to this - Multilevel Feeds or something ?

**Note:** the handling of the multilevel taxonomies should be done in just a single CSV file.

[image]

Comment: Until now, no one has approached with a definite solution, for a problem which is enormously simple in any other CMS or PHP-only approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by double running an import with only one master CSV and using the **Skip hash check** & **Update existing terms** settings within your importer.

Feeds tracks each imported item in the `feeds_item` table. As entries are imported, it adds the imported `guid` to the table and stores hashed value of the imported row within `hash`. This hash value is checked upon reprocessing so Feeds can skip any unnecessary updating (if the source data hasn't changed it doesn't need reprocessing).

If **Skip hash check** is enabled with **Update existing terms** set to *Update existing terms*, this forces Feeds to update regardless. For your purposes, the first import run will ensure that each feed item is in the `feeds_item` table. On the second import run, the hierarchy integrity will be restored as each pguid will have a valid `guid` reference in the `feeds_item` table.

Comment: But if I have, let's say, 5 levels of hierarchy, I must run the running 5 consecutive times?

Comment: No, the depth is irrelevant, the important thing is there's a guid/entity id relationship in the `feeds_item` table. This will exist for items after the first pass.

Comment: I will try it with your options. It seems a clever solution, but still don't know how and when to stop making passes. Will try it.

Comment: I'm assuming this is file upload that's batch processing the CSV in portions. I just tried it with sample CSV, making sure to run it again after the initial import. As long as it gets a 2nd pass that updates all existing terms, it should set all parent guid to each taxonomy entity that was imported in on the first run.